# .htaccess file for redirecting domain to subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several domains pointing into same documentroot in my web server.
Lets call this `/public` folder
Then i have 4 folders in this public folder

- public/domain1.com
- public/domain2.com
- public/domain3.com
- public/domain4.com

I need a `.htaccess` file for redirecting the requests to subfolders that matches the domain in the url so if the visitors comes to `domain1.com`, the web server should load the files from `public/domain1.com`

- I dont want to put .htaccess file to every folder/domain. Only one `.htaccess` file in `public_html`
- I dont want to add domain name to .htaccess file every time i go buy one domain and redirect it to webserver. It should work dynamically.

So in short, I want to buy a domain create a folder named `domain.com` in public folder. Once i redirect my dns to my server it should start working from corresponding folder without any other work.

Comment: Why not just use virtual host configurations? This is what they are for.

Comment: Have a look at this, it can help you https://serverfault.com/questions/291891/apache2-dynamic-documentroot-depending-on-url

Comment: I agree, a correct vhosts setup seems a far easier and better solution that .htaccess. You can read more about VHosts [Here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: well if it is possible i want to use .htaccess because i dont want to edit/create any file everytime i redirect a domain to my server. it seems i have to edit conf file for every domain in vhosts which i dont want to. I want it to be dynamic if it is possible.

Comment: Possibly [This](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/rewriting-urls-to-host-multiple-domains-on-a-single-ip-address-with-apache/) will help you solve your problem.
My opinion however still holds - Vhosts is a far better and far easier solution.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin this is not dynamic. i dont want to edit .htaccess every time i redirect a domain.

Comment: @MikeShevach You will have to anyway, no one will do it for you, if suddenly a new site apperars. You might be able to create a script which will edit .htaccess file, but it will still be editing. Basically you are looking for files that can change themselves, there are no such plain text files, and .htaccess is plain text

Comment: i am already doing this with the code below: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: the problem is there is a loop. and i have to to add .htaccess to also subfolders which i am looking to avoid if possible. so what u said is not true that i have to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also would *strongly* recommend to use virtual hosts for such setup. But your specific question is about a dynamic rewriting to map requested host names (referred to as "domains" in your question) to folders.This should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RequestCond %{REQUST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^ /public/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

You could also add a test for the folder which would allow for a special error document:

```
RewriteEngine on

RequestCond /public/%{HTTP_HOST} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /error_host_not_found.php

RequestCond %{REQUST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^ /public/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).